# SQLAlchemy and PostGreSQL with Insert Rule which do nothing (duplicate)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, rules

I'm creating a rest api with Flask SQLAlchemy, and PostGreSQL.

My Table history

[image: table_history]

```
class H(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "history"
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True
    )
    one_data = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        nullable=False
    )
    count = db.Column(
        db.Integer
    )
```

My Rule :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE history_no_duplicate 
  AS ON INSERT TO history WHERE 
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM history WHERE count = NEW.count)
  DO INSTEAD NOTHING
```

Directly in SQL, all insertions are working.

My SQLAlchemy code for inserting data :

```
def save(history_data):
    db.engine.execute(
        db.insert(
            History.__table__, history_data
        )
    )
save({
    "one_data": 1,
   "count": 1
})
```

Without the rule, this script is working, but when I insert the rule, SQL Alchemy returns an error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (psycopg2.NotSupportedError) cannot perform INSERT RETURNING on relation "history"
HINT:  You need an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.
```